# Running shell script automatically in UNIX / linux server

Tags: php, linux, shell

I want my web server to run a .sh script that runs a series of .jar files. I want this to happen as soon as the server is contacted without any input from the user. A PHP or JS script would be preferable. Is it even possible to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just be careful if you'll ever deploy your script to hosting you don't have control over, shell execute is often disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at [gearman.org](http://gearman.org/). It is safer and more flexible than shell_exec().

Answer (score 1):

It is not doable in JavaScript, but you can use PHP for it. If I understand your question well, you have some utilities written in Java and you don't care about their output. The shell script would look like as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar your-jar1.jar
java -jar your-jar2.jar
...
```

and provided the name of the script is `myScript.sh` and it has the `x` flag set, you can run it from PHP by:

```
shell_exec('path-to-script/myScript.sh');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    exec ("sh your_script.sh");
?>
```

place this in your webserver root as a php file and replace your_script.sh with the name of your script.

WARNING: if you don't protect the script with a password, using for example a .htaccess file for Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html), anyone can execute that script.